# Reference a web-worker from a module with a relative path

Tags: module, typescript, requirejs, web-worker

Long-story short: I have a module `baz.ts` and a web-worker script `worker.ts` adjacent to each other in the same folder, but the worker will not load when I'm referencing it with the same relative path from the same file (in case of the worker, I'm obviously loading the js file). Modules compile to the AMD syntax.

I have the following folder layout:

```
MyApp
|-- tests
|   `-- test-a
|       |-- test.html
|       `-- test.ts
`-- lib
    |-- foo.ts
    `-- foo
        |-- 
        |-- bar.ts   <-- 'bar/worker' loaded here
        `-- bar
            |-- baz.ts
            `-- worker.ts
```

*foo.ts*, *bar.ts*, *baz.ts* are modules, *foo.ts* is imported in *tests/test-a/test.ts* which is used by the adjacent *test.html* (this is where the code runs). The rest of the dependencies are visualized easily by the folder layout: *foo.ts* imports *bar.ts*, which in turn imports *baz.ts* and creates a worker from *worker.ts* -- more precisely, from the compiled `.js` output:

**bar.ts**

```
import {Baz} from "./bar/baz";

export class Bar {
    constructor() {
        var worker = new Worker("./bar/worker.js"); // same path as the above import
        // ...
    }
}
```

See how *baz.ts* and *worker.ts* are located in the same folder relative to *bar.ts* (the corresponding `.js` files are created in place), yet the worker does not load. It tries to load the url `tests/foo/bar/worker.js`.

How can I make it so that I can reference the worker with the same relative path as I'm importing the module next to it?

Comment: If it would have tried loading it from `tests/test-a/bar/worker.js` it would make sense.  Am I correct to assume that the page is the `test.html`?

Comment: @NitzanTomer Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's weird.

Usually the requests you're making (or resource loading) is relative to the url of the loaded html file, but if that was the case then (as I wrote in the comment) it should have tried to load the worker from `tests/test-a/bar/worker.js`.

What you can do is build an absolute url for your worker and use that, something like:

```
let url = new URL("lib/foo/bar.js", window.location.origin);
let worker = new Worker(url.toString());
```

Probably not ideal, but it should work.

Comment: _"It's weird."_ -- that's an understatement. Either way, I greatly appreciate your help, it indeed seems I will need to resort either to inline workers or use absolute paths -- which are inconvenient from a module-organizing point of view, however. What is even more weird is that it's been working previously, but I'm just unable to reproduce that.

Comment: You can always place all of the workers in the same directory and then have a function somewhere which returns an absolute `URL` for a given worker name.